# Can every USB stick may be turned into a bootable USB?

Tags: operating-system, usb, mbr, bootable, usb-drive

I'm about to buy a huge amount of USB sticks in order to install a custom OS in them. Do they need a special hardware configuration to make the MBR section suitable for booting? or just by defining it is enough?

Comment: I used a dozen of USB sticks without issue. I think every USB sticks can be used to do that. Wait for a confirmation but I think you can buy any USB stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any USB stick can be turned into a bootable USB. They don't need any special configuration. I use universal USB installer software to make a bootable pen drive. You can search on YouTube. It's a 5 minutes process.

Comment: Somehow I suspected it but I needed a confident answer from another person like this one to be more comfortable about the purchase :)  thanks!